# Inequality $\left(\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\right)^2>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The inequality
$$\left(\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\right)^2>0$$
has the same solution set as

a) $(2x-1)^2 > 0$

b) $2x-1 \neq 0$

c) $2x-1 > 0$

d) None of the above

Is this equivalent to$$\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}>0 \ ? $$

Comment: This is a very bad problem, because it leaves open the question of what to do about the case $x=-\frac12$. The inequality is literally meaningless when $x=-\frac12$.

Comment: Absolutely not.  $W^2 \ge 0$ with equality holding only if $W = 0$.  So $W^2 > 0 \iff W = 0$.  So it will have the same solution set as $\frac {2x-1}{2x+1}\ne 0$.

Comment: @TonyK That's what "none of the above" covers.

Comment: @TonyK: this just means that the solution set excludes $-1/2$, nothing meaningless.

Comment: @fleablood: just so as not to confuse anybody: you meant "$W^2 > 0 \iff W \ne 0$".

Comment: @YvesDaoust: this would be a _dreadful_ question to set in an exam, because the student would be left second-guessing the examiner.

Comment: @TonyK: if the student learnt about the domain of a function (which I would assume), this is *routine* work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The question asks students to compare the solution sets of inequalities involving two functions that have different domains. Should that comparison be done over the union of those domains, or their intersection? I would say this is not obvious, and is not really a question about mathematics.

Comment: It is a bad question.  And I'm not sure whether the intended answer is b) or d) i'm inclined to go with d) but it makes me uneasy to argue $(\frac {-2}{0})^2 \not > 0$ because one can easy slip and say (and I did) $w^2 /ge 0$ and $w^2 = 0 \iff w = 0$ so $w^2 > 0$ means $w \ne 0$ and $\frac {-2}{0} \ne 0$ so... It's really not fair to expect a student to catch the logical fallacy of that in an exam question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: But things really are tricky. Suppose one of the options was "(e) $(2x-1)(2x+1)\ne 0$". I think you would agree that (e) was the expected answer. But now why isn't the solution set of (e) equal to $\mathbb C-\{-\frac12,\frac12\}$? This is not equal to the original solution set, because the domain of the $<$ operator is $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb C^2$. Here you have to compare over intersection of the domains, not their union.

Comment: @YvesDaoust true.  But what's "simple" for a mathematician is subtle and slippery for a student.  What *is* simple for a student is when asked for a solution set, to ... solve the dang thing.  And $w^2 > 0 \implies w \ne 0 \implies $ numerator not 0, we must make cases for denominators be zero to eliminate *equality* solutions but denominators equal zero mean the whole thing *ISN"T* equal so "solution is $x \ne 1/2$; if x=1/2 w^2 = 0; other wise is doesn't" is "simple".

Comment: @Yves: Joke? I meant it seriously, as a logical extension of your viewpoint.

Comment: @TonyK The solution set of an equation does not include the values of the unknown which make the expression undefined, full stop.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You seem to have missed my point. If $x$ is a complex number such that $\left(\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\right)^2$ has non-zero imaginary part, then the truth value of the inequality $\left(\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\right)^2>0$ is undefined; so $x$ does not belong to the solution set of the original inequality. But $x$ does belong to the solution set of $(2x-1)(2x+1)\ne 0$. So my hypothetical option (e) is just as flawed as option (b), according to your logic.

Comment: These tests are horrible I agree. I feel that many of the questions are so ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for your question is shortly "No", because $$\left( \frac { 2x-1 }{ 2x+1 }  \right) ^{ 2 }>0\quad \Rightarrow x\in R-\left\{ \pm \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right\} \\ \\ \frac { 2x-1 }{ 2x+1 } >0\quad \Rightarrow x\in \left( -\infty ;-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \cup \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } ;+\infty  \right) $$

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not equivalent to $\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}>0$. Instead, note that the square of any real number $z$ is non-negative, and is zero iff $z=0$; thus $\left(\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\right)^2>0$ implies $\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\ne0$, which is equivalent to $2x-1\ne0$. But $2x+1\ne0$ too because division by zero is not allowed, so the answer is (d).

Answer (score 1):

The square of any expression is zero or positive, provided it is defined. Here the expression

- is zero when $2x-1=0$,
- is undefined when $2x+1=0$.

Hence, d) i.e. $|x|\ne\frac12$.

And no, the square of an expression being positive doesn't mean that the expression is positive.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent because the square allows for "negative" values of the expression that make the inequality true when squared, stripping the square, a common mistake, only finds the "positive" values of the expression. The values of x that make the inequality true are (2x-1)^2 > 0 as long as x does not equal -1/2, which causes division by zero. Parcly Taxel writes a perfectly concise and beautiful mathematical response to the problem, I'm just illuminating the reason why.